Flutter ISAR 4.0.0: String Hex value interpreted as exponential and converted to inf
I'm using Flutter with Isar version 4.0.0 to store data, and I'm encountering an issue where a specific string value is being interpreted incorrectly upon retrieval.
When I save the string "3970e14784" in a field of type String, it gets interpreted as a number in scientific notation (hexadecimal) and shows up as "Inf" when I retrieve it.
I suspect this behavior might be due to the SQLite layer under Isar, which interprets the value as a float in scientific notation. Unfortunately, I can't directly control the data type in SQLite, as it's handled internally by Isar.
I found a similar issue here: https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/issues/743, but since I'm using Isar, I don't have direct access to how SQLite is managing the data types.
Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone have suggestions on how to prevent this string from being misinterpreted?
I will probably espace my value with an underscore or save it in base64...
Any suggestions?
Thanks
